# php regex get first youtube id form text

Tags: php, regex, youtube

how to get:

**WA4nNDfQ0wA**

form this code:

```
<p>some text here ...</p>
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WA4nNDfQ0wA?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div>some text here ...</div>
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9gypDWA6r2s?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

by using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your html is inside the `$html` variable.

```
preg_match("|.*?/embed/([\w-]+)|", $html, $m);
print $m[1];
```

If you change the `.*?` into `.*`(greedy) then it will match the last id.

Comment: thank you very much. this worked like a charm. how can I learn regex, Can you give me a good link to learn it?

Comment: You can find lot of options for learning regex using google. However you can have a look at [this site][1] for regex help. And you can use [this site][2] to get the explanation of any regex. [1]: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ [2]: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: I always found the [proftpd documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html) to have an excellent regex introduction that is noob-friendly.